# adding simple windows ui to console app

Tags: c, winforms, user-interface, console-application

I have a C console app, using VS2010, to which I would like to add a simple Window interface.  (All the program does is a simple loop: get some input from the user, run the program, produce a single number as a result, continue).  The input from the user basically involves just modifying the values of a C structure:

```
struct input {
  int howMany;
  char name[100];
  int style;
  char child[100];
  char parent[100];
  bool useShoes;
  double weight;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to pass a structure in, let the user make any changes, and get it back.  What is the easiest way to go about this for someone who doesn't want to spend a few days learning a new scripting or programming language ? (I only know C...what can I say, I was an English major...)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To create a window you need [**Form**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) class in C#,

Create the Windows Forms project in VS2010. And you can embed your code there, but you have do write extra lines of code or convert code to C# to map the user input also the console output to the Windows forms which is pretty straight forward.

Here are the easy learning MSDN links to get started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: It was because C language does not define any windowing or GUI constructs, more over he said using VS2010.

Comment: Its not that I dont know the drawbacks about having GTK which is debatable on the visual sometimes. And having powerful VS do its work n u take the backseat, I dont know which one u prefer :P

Comment: Doesn't matter - he said C, and C# isn't C - there are libraries for C that do that. In fact, C# doesn't define any windowing or GUI constructs either; they're part of a library.

Comment: Getting your answer accepted doesn't mean anything. And, C# is sure as hell not C. So, before you insult me any further, I advise you to learn the difference between C and c#. And, by the way, writing "u" instead of "you" makes you look like an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

[GTK](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) is probably the *easiest* way (but, not easy at all). [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) will be much better if you can move to C++.

Answer (score 2):

You're either going to have to learn a new language or a new framework you're not familiar with. If you want to use straight C on Windows, you can use the [Win32 API to create a window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, Win32 is old, crusty, and not as easy to use are other frameworks. If you're going to be a Windows developer, you'd be better served picking up C#.